# The layout's order changes after one button becomes invisible

Tags: java, android, button, layout

This is the original layout: http://prntscr.com/bxods5

The XML of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"

    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:onClick="editEvent"
            android:text="EDIT" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attendingEventInListviewRow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="38"
            android:height="30sp"
            android:tag="Events2goName"
            android:text="Events2go"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_arrive"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_column="37"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="selectCancelArrive"
            android:text="Nope" />
    </TableRow>   



</TableLayout>
```

The problem is, that not all the users are allowed to edit, so for some users the "EDIT" button disappears, like this:

```
if(resource==R.layout.attending_listview_row) {
        eventName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attendingEventInListviewRow);
        cancelArrive = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_arrive);
        editBtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
        editBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (myEvent != null) {
        if (myEvent.getOwner()== LocalDataBase.getCurrentUser()) {
        editBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         }
```

I still want the "NOPE" button and the Events2Go text view to stay in their places afrer it, but what actually happen is this: http://prntscr.com/bxoggo

What will be the best way to make them stick to their place?

---

**Edit:**

Now I know the problem was the difference between "GONE" and "INVISIBLE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think now you are hiding the editBtn like this

> editBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

change this to

> editBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

let me know is it works or not,if not will check

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout. Try

```
<RelativeLayout         
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel_arrive"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:onClick="editEvent"
            android:text="EDIT" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attendingEventInListviewRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="30sp"
            android:tag="Events2goName"
            android:text="Events2go"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_arrive"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="selectCancelArrive"
        android:text="Nope" />

</RelativeLayout>
```